# Regional bitmap coding in android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, canvas, bitmap

how can i write regionally several images on a big blank jpeg image(10000*10000 pixel) on device's storage?

i've tried bitmap canvas but it runs out of memory even with one image(4000*3000).
so i want to do exactly the opposite of what BitmapRegionDecoder does.

Comment: 10000 x 10000.  That's nearly 400MB!  Even 4000 x 3000 is about 47MB.  I recommend that you start by reading and understanding what a bitmap is and the difference between a bitmap and a JPEG.

Comment: You may try using native (C++) code. It doesn't depend on java stack  and can hold arrays of bigger size. You may also consider using a custom jpeg encoder to encode by lines, rather than keeping the whole image in memory.

Comment: @Simon i know the limitations and that's exactly why i don't want to work in memory and that's why i wrote on device storage and regionally. the images must be written on a blank canvas(even if the canvas is 1GB jpeg) that is already on storage but with coordinates, and i just write to it with images that are on the same storage and all of them with JPEG compression on end result. for example the function should write the given image with X and Y coordinates on the blank canvas REGIONALLY to avoid errors. if any solution comes to mind will help a lot... Thanks

Comment: @cyanide yes. the image(JPEG canvas) will be on device storage not in ram.as i wrote in response to Simon. if you know any library or sample that does demonstrate this or any one that can help, please refer me to them. Thank you.